# Compile CUDA (.cu) file into a shared object (.so) using Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, cuda

I'm a big newbie to all things code, but I need to run an LBA in Rstudio. In order to run the code, I must transform a file (lba-math.cu) into a shared object file (lba-math.so). The code to do this in a bash terminal is given for me:

```
nvcc -O2 -arch sm_35 -I/usr/include/R -Xcompiler "-fpic" -c lba-math.cu -o lba-math.o
        nvcc -arch sm_35 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 lba-math.o -o lba-math.so
```

However, when I run this command (I am using Ubuntu from a Windows computer), I get the error: `"gcc: no such file or directory"`.

The instructions for running the LBA that provided this code say that: "The library locations in the above lines may need to be changed on your own system, depending on the
install location for R."

I, however, have no idea how to change the library locations because I can't read this code very well.

My current R location is in C:\Users\tessc\OneDrive\2014\Documents

The current location for the lba-math.cu file is in C:\Users\tessc\OneDrive\2014\Documents\Work\LBA Official Code.

Does anyone have any idea how I might re-write this code?

Comment: "gcc: no such file or directory" means you do not have a compiler installed

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any reccomendations for installing a compiler?

Comment: Update: After installing gcc for my version of Ubuntu, I get the following error message:
gcc-8: error: lba-math.cu: No such file or directory
gcc-8: warning: ‘-x c++’ after last input file has no effect
gcc-8: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Does this mean that Ubuntu could not locate the file I need to convert?

Comment: That means you have a different question unrelated to this one, which has been answered and closed as a duplicate